# Wordpress won't load (connection timed out)

Tags: php, wordpress, memory, out-of-memory

For some reason my Wordpress installation has just started saying "Error - connection timed out" recently and I can't get a single page to load. At first I thought it was my local MAMP server that was having problems, but now I'm starting to think it is a problem with my Wordpress installation.

I tried the three most suggested solutions of (1) De-activating all of my plugins to see if the problem was due to a specific plugin. No fixes there. Then (2) I switched to the default "Twentyfourteen" theme to see if it was a problem with my custom theme (it wasn't). And finally (3) I tried increasing the memory limit by adding `define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M' );` to the `wp-config.php` file. This didn't work either.

Are there any other causes out there that could be causing this? Any solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to install a fresh instillation?

Answer (score 2):

If none of the steps proposed in Codex helped, then it is very likely that there's some kind of locking happening. These locks may appear when installing/upgrading is not done in the proposed manner. Restarting Apache and MySQL should delete these locks.

If the problem persists or reappears further investigation is necessary. The logfiles of the involved daemons (Apache, MySQL,...) may point you to the reason of the problem and i'm sure your OS has tools that allow you tracing process any analyzing locks, but in this case maybe reinstalling gets you faster to your goal.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is clear as shown in wordpress.org official site

http://codex.wordpress.org/Common_WordPress_Errors

Just follow the steps shown there. This helped me too.

If the site runs after switching to WordPress Twenty Fifteen Theme, then there is the problem in your theme.

But if the error exists,then you have to re-install wordpress with fresh 
database because path may be wrong in your database.

Also give you proper attention in memory limits.

Thanks

Comment: So I have to start over with a completely new Wordpress installation? How can I get my near-finished Wordpress site working again? Do I have to start over?

Comment: you can use the theme of your old site to the new installed wordpress site.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I got it mostly working. But all of my plugin settings, page templates, etc, I will have to start over?

Answer (score 1):

your problem is connection timed out error. I solve your problem. you check this point.
When your WP site tries to do more than the server capacity (means you should know how much your server can manage). This problem occurs mostly with shared hosting.
Limited memory is another common reason of it.

i found a good soluction for your problem you check this  article this is  very useful for your problem.
[Connection timed out WordPress Error](https://www.navthemes.com/connection-timed-out-wordpress-error/)

Comment: Please bring relevant content in from the link.